# Eclipse not loading android SDK

Tags: eclipse, android, installation

I have an ubuntu 8.04 x86_64 system. I installed the ia32 libraries and manually installed(i.e. untarred) Eclipse Galileo Java EE. I then installed android's ADT-0.9.5 by downloading the zip file and pointing the software source as archive.

Now I need to add the android SDK in Windows->preferences->android. However, when I select the SDK directory there and select Apply/OK, nothing happens. The next time I open preferences, the directory is there in the selection dialog, but eclipse just won't load/do anything on clicking Apply.

Could someone help me out...it is driving me crazy.

Comment: Check Eclipse's error log (Window --> Show View --> Error Log).

Comment: there is no Error Log in Windows --> Show View !
Plus I don't think there will be anything there...since it simply doesn't do ANYthing on pressing Apply/OK...its like there is no function attached to it.

Answer (score 12):

Just add a forward slash "/" at the end of the path. I had the same problem on Mac OSX and solved it by adding the "/".

Annoying

Comment: Same here with Eclipse Kepler on Windows 7. I added a "\" instead. I agree: Annoying.

Comment: For me worked by removing the "\" on win 8 eclipse kepler! Super Annoying!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I'm running on

- Eclipse Galileo SR2 for linux-32bit .
- Android sdk r07 for linux
- ADT 0.9.9. (android eclipse plug-in)

Here is the way I got to solve the problem.

Open "SKD  Readme.txt" in the folder of your android-sdk and you will see ...

> The Android SDK archive now only contains the tools. It no longer comes populated with a specific Android platform or Google add-on. Instead you use the SDK Manager to install or update SDK components such as platforms, tools, add-ons, and documentation.
>
> In order to start developing applications, you must install at least one version of the Android platform using the SDK Manager.
>
> This requires an Internet connection, so if you plan to use the SDK offline, please make sure to download the necessary components while online.
>
> To start the SDK Manager, please execute the program "tools/android".

So this is it. After you do this get back to eclipse and in the target area you will see several versions available.

Answer (score 0):

Run eclipse with *clean* flag: `path_to_eclipse_dir/eclipse -clean` (eclipse.exe on Windows)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by deleting the entire SDK folder (in my case its name was "`android-sdk-Linux`"), and then re-installing the packages.

This may seem like a simple solution, but it soved the problem for me while the other solutions didn't.